# How do I run a windows command from MediaWiki link?

Tags: hyperlink, cmd, mediawiki, exe

I would like to post a link on a Mediawiki page which when clicked opens the PUTTY console and ssh into a server. For example,

```
[file:%SystemRoot%\system32\Cmd.exe /c putty -ssh <some server>]
```

This is being rendered as plain text. This command text `%SystemRoot%\system32\Cmd.exe /c putty -ssh <some server>` works perfectly when Windows+Run.

Thoughts?

Comment: For one thing, you can't use file:// style links in MediaWiki out of the box.  You have to change the [$wgUrlProtocols](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols) config variable. Even then, I don't think you can just run cmd.exe with arguments. You would probably have to put everything you want to do in a batch script and point the link at that.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple console app that takes your input on command line args[0] then register a protocol (such as foo://) and pass the argument from the page onto that.

See: [MSDN: Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)